# Intent filter and different extra's

Tags: android

I have one activity in one application, which is supposed to run another activity in another application, while passing to it an arguments|(Through `putExtra`)

The problem is that I know that I must add something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(target);
i.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

to the target intent(activity) so the system wont override the Extra's and ill get diffrent extra's each time i run the target activity.

But when i add the setAction i get an error:

> couldnt find activity: No Activity found to handle Intent {       action=actionstring1278829343752 flags=0x10000000 (has extras) }

Any idea how could I solve it with `setAction`? maybe something I have to add also to the manifest?

Comment: How did you defined `target` ? It seams no activity found to handle Intent is because you didn't defined well the `target` intent.

Comment: It work fine as soon as i take off the setAction.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use setAction for what you're trying to achieve, you must use [putExtra][1].

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: You didnt get me right, i am not using setAction inorder to put the argument, i use it coz of this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-kee //----- 

i gotta know how i can combine between setAction and putExtra while trying to start activity in another proccess

Answer (score 0):

try First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY",value);
        intent.putExtra("KEY",VALUE);
        startActivity(intent)
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent =getIntent();
 confirm_txt =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
 String txt_put =intent.getStringExtra("KEY");
 confirm_tId.setText(txt_put);
```