# Cannot retrieve Intent Extras in Service onStart()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to launch a service from another service with certain extras. However, I can't retrieve those extras in the launched service, `.getIntExtra` returns a NullPointerException.

This is how I **launch** the service:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RefreshService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnRefresh, contentIntent);
```

And this how I'm trying to **receive** the extras in the started service:

```
@Override    
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
}
```

In my example, `mAppWidgetId` always resorts to the default value -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" it by transmitting my custom values through `.setAction` and `.setFlags` instead of `.putExtras`, which works fine. I can retrieve these with `.getAction` and `.getFlags`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds suspiciously like this: [Android keeps caching my intents Extras, how to declare a pending intent that keeps fresh extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-kee)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my case, no extra at all is (seemingly) passed to the started service, it's not a question of which is the most recent one. I tried adding the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT though, but that doesn't help :-/

Comment: ACtually, wait, those are two conflicting statements - at first, you say getIntExtra throws a NPE (indicating that intent is null), but then you say that it returns -1 (indicating that either the extra doesn't exist, or you actually pass in -1 - did you verify that you pass in the right value?).

Comment: If you look at line four of the second code-block: getIntExtra resolves to "-1", as this has been specific as the default value (in case that the intent extra doesn't exist). If I would query the extra without specifying a default value, I would get a NPE.