# Android: Recents starts incorrect activity

Tags: android, android-activity, deeplink

I am developing an android app which has 2 methodes of starting. 
One is the normal way by pressing the app icon on the phone.
The other method is with a deep link from a website.

The deeplink also sends some data which the app needs to do some "stuff". However this should only be done once. 
When the deeplink activity is finished it start the main activity. However when I press back (on the device) and open the app from recents it opens the deeplink activity again.

I could exclude the deeplink activity from the recents in the manifest. This also excludes the mainactivity from the recent apps, this should not be the case.

How do I prevent the deeplink activity from beeing started from the recent apps?

My Manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="DeeplinkActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="app_name" android:host="test" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="test" android:path="/" android:scheme="app_name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To switch to the MainActivity I do the following:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT:
This post was marked as duplicate with: [Android: Starting app from 'recent applications' starts it with the last set of extras used in an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866149/android-starting-app-from-recent-applications-starts-it-with-the-last-set-of)

However that post is regarding the same activity. I want to change the root activity so when I start the app from recents it does not start the DeeplinkActivity. Yes as a workaround I could check the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY flag. But then every time the user starts the app from recents the DeeplinkActivity is opened whilst it is not needed anymore.

Setting and or clearing aditional intent values does not seem to work.
I use information from the getIntent().getData()

If you still feel as if this is a duplicate please explain.

Comment: I reopened the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that both `DeepLinkActivity` and `MainActivity` are in the same task, so when the user selects the app from the list of recent tasks, Android will either bring an existing task to the foreground, or if there is no existing task (with live/active activities in it), start the `Activity` that was the root `Activity` in the most recent task. You can't predict which `Activity` will be the root `Activity`, since the task could be started with either `DeepLinkActivity` or `MainActivity`, depending on which one the user chose first.

You really need to have 2 separate tasks to do this. One task will have your `DeepLinkActivity` in it, and this task should be excluded from the "recent task list". The other task will have your `MainActivity` in it.

I assume that `MainActivity` has the `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER, even though your posted manifest does not show this.

Your manifest should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="DeeplinkActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="app_name" android:host="test" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="test" android:path="/" android:scheme="app_name" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You definitely do not need `launchMode="singleTask"` for `MainActivity` and you probably don't need it for `DeepLinkActivity` either (that depends on what else you do with this).

Specifying `taskAffinity=""` ensures that `DeepLinkActivity` is not launched into the same task as `MainActivity`, and allows you to launch `MainActivity` from `DeepLinkActivity` in a separate task. NOTE: Without specifying `taskAffinity`, both activities will end up in the same task, even though you specify `launchMode="singleTask"` for both of them.

Specifying `excludeFromRecents="true"` on `DeepLinkActivity` tells Android that the task with `DeepLinkActivity` as its root activity should not appear in the list of recent tasks.

When you launch `MainActivity` from `DeepLinkActivity`, you should do this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and make sure that you call `finish()` on `DeepLinkActivity`.

If necessary you can also add `noHistory="true"` to `DeepLinkActivity`, but I don't think it is necessary. If the user is in `DeepLinkActivity` and gets an incoming phone call, after the phone call is ended, `DeepLinkActivity` should be displayed. If you specify `noHistory="true"`, `DeepLinkActivity` would be finished immediately when the user accepts the incoming phone call.

Let me know if this is clear and works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. Indeed this is the way to solve my Issue. As a small side note.

Comment: for me it was required to use the noHistory. Because in you example there is a call. When the user returns to the app the process needs to restart.

Comment: If I open an activity from Notification, say, A then go to B after finishing A. Then press Back, I open MainActivity. If I press back app closes then if I open the app from Recents. It Opens the Same A Activity then goes to B. I want it to open the Launcher Activity just like clicking on the Would.

Comment: @AmanVerma you should open a new question for this problem. Making a comment in an answer to another question is not the way to get the right attention to your problem. In the meantime, have a look at my answer to this question which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19820057/769265

Comment: Already asked the question here yesterday... Please Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965236/opening-the-app-from-recents-opening-the-old-activity-in-android