# Opening the App from Recents opening the old activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, back-stack

I have 4 Activities: Launcher, MainActivity(SingleTask), NotificationActivity, ExampleActivity.

When the user clicks on the notification, **NotificationActivity** opens then **ExampleActivity** and finishes the **NotificationActivity**.

When I press back **MainActivity** opens. Now if I press back, the application gets closed. If the user then opens the app from the recent Tasks, **NotificationActivity** opens then **ExampleActivivty**. But if the user opens the app from the icon, Launcher Activity opens then MainActivity.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: please post your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly this problem is covered in my answer to this question:

[Remove data from notification intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent/19820057#19820057)

When you select your app from the list of recent tasks, Android remembers how the app was originally launched (in your case, via `Notification`) and starts the app again the same way. This can be considered a bug or a a feature, depending on what you expect to happen.

I've got a few suggestions in my answer that you can use to deal with it.