# android: getting same value from Intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, extras

I am doing this to create a Intent.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Startup.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("url", contentUrl);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

On getting the extra,

```
CharSequence url = this.getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("url");
```

There are many Intents with their respective url values. But I also get back the same value inside onCreate() of Startup class.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: are these both different activities..

Comment: Sorry I do not understand by different activities..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should answer you query for sure...cheers :)
[Android keeps caching my intents Extras, how to declare a pending intent that keeps fresh extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-kee)

Comment: This works!

    notificationIntent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());
   
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

Use this

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

instead of this

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

and check the results