# Broadcast receiver not getting extra

Tags: android

I have an app using a tab bar host api that I found and I am trying to use it to change activities when I receive a Sms message.

The receiver that was build into this tab host is the following:

```
public class ChangeTabBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int index = intent.getExtras().getInt(CURRENT_TAB_INDEX);
        setCurrentTab(index);
    }
}
```

This is defined in the ScrollableTabActivity.java, then the ScrollableTabHost extends this and is called in the bellow method when a Sms is reveived:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ScrollableTabHost.class);    
intent2.putExtra("CURRENT_TAB_INDEX", index);
intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent2);
```

There is also an OnTabChanged listener build in which prints the index of the tab to the log. When i send a text from the emulator I shows that the tab was changed to index 0 twice, no matter which index I try to set it to. 
I have been looking for a while and cant find why I am getting 0 instead of the index that I send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured this out. Turns out I was just did not have to code setup the way the tab bar api wanted it the correct code to switch to a new activity in one of my tabs is as follows:

```
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(ScrollableTabHost.ACTION_CHANGE_TAB);    
    intent2.putExtra(ScrollableTabHost.CURRENT_TAB_INDEX, 4); 
    context.sendBroadcast( intent2 );
```

If anyone is wondering the api is from https://github.com/honcheng/ScrollableTabHost-for-Android
Its a pretty good tab host.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a similar issue to this : [Android keeps caching my intents Extras, how to declare a pending intent that keeps fresh extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-ke)

So you can maybe try to give some *unique id* to your intents when you are setting the action:

```
intent.setAction("smsaction" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

to make sure the latest one is the valid one (hence the *extras* and the *ids*)

On the other hand... you are not using `PendingIntents` so this may be all irrelevant. If so please ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this was not the issue.