# Android: always got the old intent when opening links from browser through Recent Apps key

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to achieve "launch App from web" and I have 2 ready-to-use links in my webpage. Opening either of the links did call the activity `SchemeRedirectActivity` and get the correct intent. The problem is when I store(don't close) the links in phone browser separately and:

open one link from browser > press `Recent Apps` key(e.g.the right hardware key on device) > open another link,
`getIntent()` always gives me the old intent except the first time opening each link.

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SchemeRedirectActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

SchemeRedirectActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = getIntent(); //always got the old intent here
    Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

The solutions from internet don't work for my case, even if I add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` / `"singleTop"` to manifest file, my `onNewIntent()` is never launched:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Log.d("intent", "onNewIntent "); //never launched
    Uri data = intent.getData();

}
```

What is wrong with the process and how can I fix it please?
*Sorry if my question is not clear, thanks.