# Intent filterEquals and filterHashCode are no longer invoked when creating pending intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I create several notifications with similar pending intents but different values within.

When clicking on any of the notifications, only the last registered intent is fired.

It used to work in the past because the `filterEquals()` and `filterHashCode()` were invoked and this made the uniqueness possible. Now, when I put breakpoints in these methods, they aren't invoked anymore.

Ideas on what happened? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I use PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT because I update the progress bar of the notification.

Comment: My Intent is class specific, so after defining a unique action everything worked out smoothly. It should have worked when I overwritten the filters methods :(

Comment: I don't know what changed but thanks to Ben and Amit, I could bypass the problem by either defining a unique requestCode or action.