# I get the same extra data from notifications even if I create some intents with different data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I copied and paste from this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification) and tried to `PutExtra`.

I tapped `button1`, `button2` and `button3`, and then tapped a notification from `button1`, but `ResultActivity` was started with `button3`, why?

I want to be displayed as `button1`. Do you know a solution?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(listener);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(listener);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    notifyNotification("button1");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    notifyNotification("button2");
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    notifyNotification("button3");
                    break;
            }

        }
    };

    private int mId = 0;

    private void notifyNotification(String value) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText(value);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("value", value); // ***** I added this code *****

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

        mId++;
    }
}

public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("value");

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android keeps caching my intents Extras, how to declare a pending intent that keeps fresh extras?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-ke)

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies on `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and using same `PendingIntent`'s request code, which is 0. That way, the all notifications' `Intent` will be updated to the last `Button` pressed.

Try to also use different request code for each `PendingIntent`.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        mId, // update to use same ID with notification's ID
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! I've resolved this problem. This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3140371/2439192) is also well.

Comment: Thank you so much.This is Perfect

Comment: Try to also use different request code for each PendingIntent. is the point for me

Answer (score 0):

```
long mId = System.currentTimemiles();
```

Comment: Please share some explanation for that code such that others can learn from it